# How to insert to a database with foreach?

Tags: php, mysql

Hi a have a small problem. I can't insert into db array... this is my code

```
$qurum1 = implode('|',$_POST['qurum1']);
$qurum = explode('|', $qurum1);
foreach ($qurum as $value) {
$query2 = "INSERT INTO test (data_id, col2) VALUES ('$id', '$value')"; 
}
```

This code inserts only last value

Comment: You have to actually execute the query inside the loop.

Comment: also include your query function in the loop

Comment: Learn about prepared Statements to prevent SQL injection

Comment: I recommend not to run queries inside of loops, you should probably create one INSERT statement which inserts all of the values at once. Also you are open to SQL injection, have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1) SO question.

Comment: @TobiasF. Why not in a Loop?

Comment: check -  http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.multiple-statement.php

Comment: your comments are all but useful. @Jabbar look at this link: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp . You can find useful info about how to insert data to database. good for the beginning

Comment: @Jens Because when you run queries within a loop this can have an impact on the performance, so your code will run slower.

Comment: @Jens - because you uneccesarily call database multiple times, and the most expensive part of executing a query is connecting to database

Comment: _“your comments are all but useful”_ ... said the person linking to w3schools. Oh, the irony.

Comment: why are you executing query multiple times just grab the values inside loop and insert in one single shot.

Comment: One has to wonder where the OP is with all this. Seems like this is an *"argue amongst your/ourselves"*.

Comment: @Fred-ii- beginning to feel like the OP

Comment: linking w3schools to a person who asks how to execute simple query. it is enough if you're a beginner.

Comment: @Akin No need to hold that weight on *your* shoulders. I edited my comment up there btw ;-) see the latter.

Comment: yeah @Fred-ii- lots of contradicting opinions here

Comment: Then there's the POST's origin and if it is in fact an array and the api used to connect with is unknown.

Comment: OP is officially MIA.

Comment: I need every time new row. I do not need all values in one row

Comment: can't you create a new merged array which contains the data_id and col_2 values. Then use that array in your foreach loop so the value of id does not repeat itself.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You need to add the MySQL query inside the foreach() function, as well:

```
foreach ($qurum as $value) {
    $query2 = "INSERT INTO test (data_id, col2) VALUES ($id, $value)";
    mysqlExecute($query2);
}
```

Note that `mysqlExecute()` does not exist, you need to use your own function to execute the query.

Also note that executing SQL statements in a loop is not recommended because it slows down performance when executing multiple queries. If your web page does not have too much load or you're just practicing it's fine either way.

Comment: why does this answer have 2 downvotes?

Comment: Someone didn't like my solution. It's not correct from a performance point of view, but it answers the OP's question. This is not a matter of opinion, it's a matter of answering a question.

Comment: OP provided the code. OP's loop is wrong.

Comment: It is wrong, he needed the query execution function. This answers his question. I would have used a different structure for this, but I don't know the OP's context. I don't think the downvotes are justified.

Comment: yeah @Ciprian your solution would fix OP's problem

Comment: @Jens it is not. The code is correct. $id and $value will be recognized as PHP variables and correctly inserted

Comment: @boroboris I do not think so, it means that the id is same for all records

Comment: @Jens Are you out of mind, code is correct. He just focusing on the error. why are you just looking at syntax problem? its all about solution.

Comment: One has to wonder how OP plans to deal with the ID variable. Is it the same id value?

Comment: I think a permanent solution would be to have like a generic insert function that takes a key value array. That way you can throw the whole array into the function and it saves them.

Comment: Could you write, please?

Comment: I did like @Ciprian said

Comment: @JabbarGuliyev If you're happy with the result, you can mark it as the accepted answer (and/or upvote it).

Comment: @Ciprian I have already done it

Comment: @JabbarGuliyev Cheers!

Comment: So many downvotes for an accepted answer. What's your reasoning? Why don't you add a comment?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<form method="post">
    <input id="value1" value="value1"  name="qurum1[]" type="checkbox">
    <input id="value2" value="value2"  name="qurum1[]" type="checkbox">
    <input value="21"  name="id" type="hidden">
    <input type="submit">
</form>

<?php
    if(isset($_POST['qurum1'])){
        $invite = $_POST['qurum1'];
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $dbObj=mysqli_connect("$dbhost","$dbusername","$dbpasswd","$dbname") or die('Could not connect to DB : ' .mysqli_connect_error());
        foreach ($qurum as $value) {
            $query2 = "INSERT INTO test (data_id, col2) VALUES ('$id', '$value')"; 
            $ins_sql = mysqli_query($dbObj,$query2);
        }
    }
?>
```

Now i have added the 'id' as hidden element.

Comment: I have changed the code with mysqli_connect()

Comment: I already have all $vars, I just need the $qurum array correctly insert to db

Comment: Please post the data in $qurum variable.

Comment: $_POST['qurum1'] gets values from checkbox qurum1[], so $qurum1 is like 1|2|3...

Comment: @JabbarGuliyev is $qurum1 a list of all id's?

Comment: @Jens $id is different and has 1 value of the post (for ex. $id = 21 and $qurum1 = 1|2|3). The table test has its own id,which has auto_increment. test table colunms is id(auto_increment), data_id(21), col2(1|2|3)

Comment: I have edited the code. I hope, that is the one you looking for..

Comment: @JabbarGuliyev If i understand you in the right way you store values as "cvs". Which is no good idea

Comment: @Ashok, no, because $id already have a value...

Comment: @Jens what do you offer?

Comment: Please just print the content whatever that you got in $qurum1 and $id. (all the from your code)

Comment: @JabbarGuliyev normalize your table